# How to calculate 'spread of gaussian function'?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to implement Aggregation Pheromone density based classification for land use map problem. In the paper, the formula to calculate pheromone intensity deposited at x by ant aj (located at xj) is calculated as :

```
T(aj,x) = e^-d(xj,x)^2/2del^2
```

where, d(xj,x) represents the euclidean distance between two points,

del denotes the spread of gaussian function.

I want to know two things : First, what is this and second, how to calculate this.

Comment: The spread of a gaussian function is a parameter of the gaussian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function

Comment: The value of gaussian function is scalar, right. My question is : For my project, I have an array containing the co-ordinate values of an image. Clearly, afaiu, I should the apply the gaussian function on the intensity value because applying them on co-ordinates makes no sense. Am I right?

Comment: AS far as I understand, `T(aj,x)` is your gaussian, `aj` is the ant located at `xj` (so `xj` is a pair of coordinate) and `x` is a pixel of your image (so a pair of coordinate too). The value of   `T(aj,x)` is the pheromone intensity. So for each pixel of coordinate `(a,b)`, you calculate `T(aj,(a,b))`, and `d(xj,x)` sould be something like `sqrt((xj[0]-x[0])^2+(xj[1]-x[1])^2)`

Comment: The value of `del` is arbitrary, you are the only one to know what it could be...

Comment: Right. What do you mean by that I am the only one to know what it could be?

Comment: `del` is 1 of the parameters of the gaussian: `xj` is the position of its maximum, `del` is a measure of its width. These number can be arbitrarily chosen among real numbers and define the precise gaussian you use. So you have to choose `del` (in your case, I guess some units).